# $_FILES['']['size'] - does PHP check file size on server side?

Tags: php, security, file-upload, file

when a file is uploaded using a PHP script, which is the best way to check file size?

`$_FILES['']['size']` OR `filesize()`?

the value in `$_FILES['']['size']` - does PHP check the file size in the server, or is it the value sent by the browser while uploading the file?

`$_FILES['']['type']` - is the value sent by the browser, and has a security problem while uploading the file. is `$_FILES['']['size']` like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have the manual here

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

size is the actual size of the file on the server

Comment: you're welcome you can thank me by marking this as answered =D