# Security concern regarding $_FILES['']['size'] (vs filesize())

Tags: php, security, file-upload

In order to improve my development, I want to understand wich is better: `$_FILES['']['size']` or `filesize()`.

I would also like to understand the advantages, disadvantages and differences between one option and another.

[$_FILES['']['size'] - does PHP check file size on server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4352620/2239417) and [What's the difference in these ways of determining uploaded file size in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6297945/2239417), resolves a little part, but I want to understand a bit more.

For example, [$_FILES['']['size'] - does PHP check file size on server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4352620/2239417) says:

> size is the actual size of the file on the server

But not explains the differences between `$_FILES['']['size']` and `filesize()` and wich is safer.

And [What's the difference in these ways of determining uploaded file size in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6297945/2239417), the same there is no explanation of wich is safer and why.

Maybe there is no difference from a security point of view?

Thank's!

I've searched the Internet and the PHP documentation but can't find the answers I'm looking for.

Comment: What *exactly* is unclear from "this and this"? What exactly is unclear about the disadvantage labeled "wasteful"? What exactly is unclear about the difference put as "goes out and gets the file size from the drive, even though it's already populated"?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Exactly, with POV I mean Point Of View". I would like to know if one option is safer than the other and why

Comment: Both are the same when it comes to security. `$_FILES['']['size']` measures the size for you, when the file is uploaded, whereas with `filesize()` you do the same again. So, the question remains why you assume there's any difference when it comes to security? The size of a file is something fixed, and not something that, in itself, poses a security risk.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i suppose that if the size could be spoofed, then it can be somewhat considered as a risk, as if you set a limitation for, say, 100Kb and someone uploads 100Mb still pretending it's under 10Kb. As it could be with the type. So the concern iutself is somewhat justified. But it should be resolved by existing answers

Comment: exactly @YourCommonSense an example to worry about security is if the size could be spoofed

Comment: $_FILES'']['size'] is the actual size of the file on the server. Actual means actual

Comment: Well, I can find people who [argue the same](https://dev.to/einlinuus/how-to-upload-files-with-php-correctly-and-securely-1kng), but would this be really true? No prove is given at all, and it is probably an advertorial. It wouldn't be the first lie to make some money. I trust the answer [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014321/) more. It would not make any sense to have such an obvious hole in the security of PHP code (yes, I know it's reputation). A detailed answer, with code, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564656/).

Comment: Anyway, this was a nice question, albeit not very well worded, but that can be improved. Regrettably, just like with so many other question, lots of duplicates do exist.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware both [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014321/can-you-trust-file-size-given-by-files-array-in-php) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564656/can-files-size-be-forged) helped me a lot. 

Probably I can ask the question in better way. Sorry.

Thank's for your comments.